# Postgres: while "table has rows" loop...

Tags: postgresql, while-loop, is-empty

Let us say, we have the following table my_table:

```
id   Col1         Col2
1    some data    some data
2    some data    some data 
3    some data    some data  
4    some data    some data
```

Additionally let us assume that there is an update process of the table and after its execution the table ends up with lower number of rows.

We want to iterate this process until "my_table" has no rows. It is certain that after a finite number of iterations of the update process, the table has zero rows.

How correct is to try sth like this:

```
while (select count(id) from my_table) != 0 loop
  update process
  ...;
end loop;
```

Comment: Updates in SQL don't delete records, they (possibly) modify the data in records which already exist.

Comment: yes, you re right. My omission to mention that the update process concerns not only the 'my_table' but also an 'other_table'. Updating the latter leads to lower number of rows in the first. Thanks for the comment, but the answer below caught the point.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add transactions to make it reliable, otherwise you have no guarantee that some other user or process won't add a row after you count them but before update runs. You actually need:

```
while not done
   begin transaction
      if (count rows > 0)
         do something that expects rows
      else
         done
   end transaction
```